# Constructor this() unnecessary?

Tags: java, constructor, this, superclass, default-constructor

There was a class U1 that was extending class U.
Class U was empty...

In the constructor of U1 there was this first line, calling the constructor of the superclass...

```
public U1(Plate plate, int order)
{
   super(plate, order);
...

}
```

Now I want to delete class U1 and do in class U whatever was done in U1 so far...
So, now I will not need to call constructor of the superclass since class U is not gonna have any superclass...

Is `this(plate, order)` unnecessary and can I omit it?

This is how my constructor of U is gonna look like:

```
public U(Plate plate, int order)
    {
       this(plate, order);
    ...

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unnecessary and I would expect it results in a stack overflow, because you call the constructor itself from within the constructor.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even get far enough to be a stack overflow. It never makes it to runtime.

Answer (score 7):

It will result in a compilation error.  The [JLS section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) says:

> *"It is a compile-time error for a constructor to directly or indirectly invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor invocations involving `this`."*

In this case, the constructor invokes itself directly.

Comment: +1, nice catch! `javac` does indeed come back with the error `recursive constructor invocation`.

Answer (score 1):

in sample as follows we will get Error: recursive constructor invocation,

```
class TestConstruct{
 public TestConstruct(){
  this();
  System.out.println("constructor of Test class");
 }//end of constructor 
}//end of class TestConstruct
public class AppConstruct{ 
 public static void main(String[] a){
 Test t = new Test(); 
 }//end of main
}//end of AppConstruct
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that u can ommit it. You have to ommit it otherwise it would act as a never ending recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

We call super() in the constructor to initialize the instance variables inherited from super class,so there is no need to call super() if there is no super class--exception java.lang.Object.
If where are multi-constructors,we can do this() to call other constructors,but don't call
constructor itself,that cause the bad things as previous people refered to.